# I need to create a list of folder directories that do not contain a file with a specific name using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**Problem:**
I am running a large number of simulations (~14000) and each simulation if executed correctly is supposed to generate 10 different files and 1 folder containing 3 files. 
Sometimes if the simulation is not executed correctly it skips that simulation and carries on with the others. Consequently, it does not generate a file called "flow.dat". A small example of my directory tree is:

```
Air_Z10_A2
+-- Des1
|   +-- 05000800
|   |   +-- flow.dat
|   |   +-- mesh.dat
|   +-- 05000850
|   |   +-- flow.dat
|   |   +-- mesh.dat
+-- Des2
|   +-- 05000800
|   |   +-- mesh.dat
|   +-- 05000850
|   |   +-- flow.dat
|   |   +-- mesh.dat
Air_Z10_A3
+-- Des1
|   +-- 05000800
|   |   +-- flow.dat
|   |   +-- mesh.dat
+-- Des2
|   +-- 05000850
|   |   +-- mesh.dat
```

**Question:**
I wanted to use bash to generate a list of all the directories (folder names with their path) that **DO NOT** include flow.dat such that I know which specific cases did not run. So basically a method that would give me output in the form of :

```
/home/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A2/Des2/05000800
/home/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A3/Des2/05000850
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: To get better help, can you be more specific and add a representative directory tree, the expected output for that tree, and ideally what you tried and how specifically it failed?

Comment: Did you already tried something? Please show us your code!

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you wanted, Using the `bash` shell and other utilities.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

grep -Fvf <(find /home/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A*/ -type f -name '*flow.dat' | awk -F'/' -v OFS=/ 'NF{NF-=1}1') <(find /home/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A*/ -type f | awk -F'/' -v OFS=/ 'NF{NF-=1}1')
```

---

Although `grep` and `awk` together can be avoided, with just `awk`

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' <(find /home/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A*/ -type f -name '*flow.dat' | awk -F'/' -v OFS=/ 'NF{NF-=1}1') <(find /home/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A*/ -type f | awk -F'/' -v OFS=/ 'NF{NF-=1}1')
```

Or just `grep`

```
grep -Fvf <(find /home/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A*/ -type f -name '*flow.dat' | grep -Po '.*(?=/+[^\s]+$)') <(find /home/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A*/ -type f | grep -Po '.*(?=/+[^\s]+$)')
```

- The embedded `awk` and `grep` is used to remove the last field separated by a `/` See [Cut last field of a string.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234432/how-to-delete-the-last-column-of-a-file-in-linux)
- The script just basically checks if the string `flow.dat` is in the files ( a fifo ). See [prints lines only in file1 but not in file2](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036)
- The `<( )` is called [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html), which basically just creates a temp file (a fifo), see the output of `ls -l <(:)` the `:`  does nothing, see `help :`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a pretty regular directory structure and know according to which pattern the files are named, you could do a

```
diff  <(find Air* -name flow.dat -exec dirname {} \;|sort) <(ls -d Air*/Des*/[0-9]*)
```

The first argument to `diff` is the list of directories having a flow.dat file, and the second argument is the list of all directories.

Usually it is risky to process the output of `ls` or similar commands further, because a newline character in a file name would ruin the logic. In your case, you know what the filenames look like, so I would not worry about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

## There is a quick an efficient way:

Finding all directories who contain `mesh.dat` but does'nt contain `flow.dat`.

```
find . -type f -name mesh.dat -exec bash -c '
    for i;do
        [ -f ${i%/*}/flow.dat ] || echo ${i%/*};
    done
  ' - {}   +
```

As a function:

```
missingFlow () { 
    find $1 -type f -name mesh.dat -exec bash -c '
    for i;do
        [ -f ${i%/*}/flow.dat ] || echo ${i%/*};
    done
  ' - {} +
}
```

Then

```
missingFlow /tmp/usr/documents/
/tmp/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A3/Des2/05000850
/tmp/usr/documents/Air_Z10_A2/Des2/05000800
```